# Analytical solution to $A \cos (x + \alpha) - B \cos(3x + \beta) = 0$

Tags: trigonometry, roots

I would like to know if the equation

> $$A \cos (x + \alpha) - B \cos(3x + \beta) = 0 \qquad\text{with}\qquad A > 0,\; B >0$$

can be solved analytically to find its roots on the variable $x$. $A$, $B$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are given parameters. All quantities are real numbers.

If the equation has no analytical solution, I would like to understand why not, and I would appreciate suggestions on simple methods on how to find the roots.

Comment: Theoretically I cannot be of much help except saying that$\ldots$ most trigonometric equations allow no analytic solutions. Practically, if you have Mathematica you can try the code: $\text{Solve}[A>0\land B>0\land (\alpha |\beta )\in \mathbb{R}\land A \cos (\alpha +x)-B \cos (\beta +3 x)=0,x,\mathbb{R}]$

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Unfortunately, I don't have mathematica but thank you for your suggestion. That would be a very simple method. But if by chance the equation has no analytical solution, i wonder what would be mathematica's result...

Comment: From one Blue to another ... You can expand the terms into cosines and sines of $x$ (and $\alpha$ and $\beta$). With a bit of work, you can eliminate the sines to get a polynomial in $\cos x$. It's unlikely that the polynomial is "nice", though. A computer algebra system like Mathematica or Sage is *really* helpful for slogging through all the symbol-crunching. I'll post an answer later.

Comment: @blue I tried this before too! The problem I found was that if you look at this $\cos (3x) = -3cos(x) sin^2(x)+cos^3(x)$ than I will have powers of 3 and mixed sin and cos... in particular I would have to convert sin to cos (just like you said) but as far as I know, a square root would appear and to get rid of that I get term on cos to the sixth power... wow :) honestly, If you think there is a work around to this... I am very interested. And thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start here (with $a$ and $b$ for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, to save typing effort):
$$A \cos(x+a) = B \cos(3x + b)$$
Expanding, and writing $c$ and $s$ for $\cos x$ and $\sin x$, we get
$$A (\; c \cos a - s \sin a \;)  = B (\; c^3 \cos b - 3 c^2 s \sin b - 3 c s^2 \cos b + s^3 \sin b \;)$$
We can reduce the powers of sine by replacing $s^2 = 1 - c^2$:
$$A (\; c \cos a - s \sin a \;) = B (\; 4 c^3 \cos b - 3 c \cos b + s \sin b - 4 c^2 s \sin b \;)$$
Isolating $s$:
$$s(\; A \sin a + B \sin b - 4 c^2 \sin b \;) = c (\; A \cos a - 4 B c^2 \cos b + 3 B \cos b \;)$$
Squaring, again replacing $s^2 = 1 - c^2$, and tidying-up a bit:
$$\begin{align}
0 &= 16 B^2 c^6 \\
&- 8 B c^4 \;(\; 3 B + A \cos(a-b) \;) \\
&+ c^2 \;(\; A^2 + 9 B^2 + 6 A B \cos a \cos b + 10 A B \sin a \sin b \;) \\
&-\;(\;A \sin a + B \sin b\;)^2
\end{align}$$

This cubic in $c^2$ "can" be solved explicitly, but *Mathematica*'s brute-force solution is *not* pretty. For a taste, here's one root:

$$\frac{4 A^2 B^2 \cos ^2(a-b)+6 B^2 \sqrt[3]{8 A^3 B^3 \cos ^3(a-b)-9 A B^3 \left(A^2+3 B^2\right) \cos (a-b)-18 A^2 B^4 \cos (2 a)+3 \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{B^6 (A \sin (a-b)-B \sin (2 b))^2 \left(8 A^3 B \cos (3 a-b)+A^4+18 A^2 B^2-27 B^4\right)}+3 A^2 B^4 \cos (2 b)-9 B^6 \cos (2 b)\right)}+2 A B \cos (a-b) \sqrt[3]{8 A^3 B^3 \cos ^3(a-b)-9 A B^3 \left(A^2+3 B^2\right) \cos (a-b)-18 A^2 B^4 \cos (2 a)+3 \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{B^6 (A \sin (a-b)-B \sin (2 b))^2 \left(8 A^3 B \cos (3 a-b)+A^4+18 A^2 B^2-27 B^4\right)}+3 A^2 B^4 \cos (2 b)-9 B^6 \cos (2 b)\right)}+\left(8 A^3 B^3 \cos ^3(a-b)-9 A B^3 \left(A^2+3 B^2\right) \cos (a-b)-18 A^2 B^4 \cos (2 a)+3 \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{B^6 (A \sin (a-b)-B \sin (2 b))^2 \left(8 A^3 B \cos (3 a-b)+A^4+18 A^2 B^2-27 B^4\right)}+3 A^2 B^4 \cos (2 b)-9 B^6 \cos (2 b)\right)\right)^{2/3}+6 A B^3 \cos (a+b)-3 A^2 B^2+9 B^4}{12 B^2 \sqrt[3]{8 A^3 B^3 \cos ^3(a-b)-9 A B^3 \left(A^2+3 B^2\right) \cos (a-b)-18 A^2 B^4 \cos (2 a)+3 \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{B^6 (A \sin (a-b)-B \sin (2 b))^2 \left(8 A^3 B \cos (3 a-b)+A^4+18 A^2 B^2-27 B^4\right)}+3 A^2 B^4 \cos (2 b)-9 B^6 \cos (2 b)\right)}}$$

Some simplification is possible. (For instance, we can move some $B^6$ and $(A \sin (a-b)-B \sin (2 b))$ factors out of some square roots.) But whether this can be wrestled into a useful form ... I can't say for sure, but I'm not optimistic.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I think the first part of the derivation proves it has an analytical solution, which honestly was my main question here. I did not believe on this solution before because I though it would have some c^5 or c^3 terms. You are right, the solution is somewhat cumbersome to be useful. Nevertheless your derivation until you bring Mathematica was useful to me. Too late here, I will check all the steps tomorrow. But thanks! I will mark it as the answer now.

Comment: oh I am so glad that I was wrong, ha ha. Good work.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever Mathematica recognizes an equation allowing no analytic solution (with some specific definition as to what that means in Mathematica), it just spits the output exactly the same as the input.

btw, mine is Mathematica 10.

[image]

Comment: I'm posting this just to show the snapshot. Having said what I said, sometimes the reason for useless output is that the input is not formulated correctly. Maybe someone who's an expert on Mathematica can weigh in on that. Personally I actually hope I was wrong.

Comment: eheh... thanks for this! I never looked to mathematica output :) first time! Moreover, I have to verify, but I honestly think that he gave you the solution! :) I say this because I was trying to solve it by my self an hour ago and I got into something near that... I will give it a try and I will come back! I think that depending on the parameters, slightly different solutions may happen... "I'll be back" :)

Comment: Ah!! forget it! Only now I read it carefully and noticed that you where giving me an example to show what happens when mathematica can calculate the result! :) Lol the solution is so similar to something I was trying before that I thought it was the answer! I got it now! --> According to mathematica, there is no analytical solution to this problem!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I marked the other answer as the correct one but our discussion was helpful. The only reason I am saying this is that I wanted to up vote your answer but it was not possible as I have no reputation yet :) but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

REMARK.-For the particular case where the constants are such that  $\beta=3\alpha$ you have solution. In fact, 
$$A\cos(x+\alpha)=B\cos(3(x+\alpha))=4B\cos^3(x+\alpha)-3B\cos (x+\alpha)$$ Hence
$$\begin{cases}\cos(x+\alpha)=0\\\cos(x+\alpha)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{A+3B}{4B}}\end{cases}$$
Explicity, for example,$$x=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}-\alpha$$

$$**********$$

In the general case it would be useful a parameter $t$ as follows:
$$\frac{\cos(3x+\beta)}{\cos(x+\alpha)}=\frac AB\Rightarrow\begin{cases}\cos(3x+\beta)=At\\\cos(x+\alpha)=Bt\end{cases}$$ Hence each solution of $$3\arccos(Bt)-\arccos(At)=3\alpha-\beta$$ gives a solution for $x$

(According the values of $A,B,\alpha,\beta$, is there a unique solution?, none solution? )

Comment: Wow... I am interested in your comment (the last one regarding the general case). So, trying to answer your questions: given a set $A$, $B$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you have an infinite number of solutions, just like in a simple equation $\sin(x) = 0$. I think it is not possible to have none solutions, regardless of the parameters you start with. If you want, try with $A = 2.0$, $B = 1.0$, $\alpha = \pi/4$ and $\beta = \pi/2$. The first solutions should be $x = 0.94$, $x = 4.08$, $x = 7.22$...

Comment: The brackets were written for you to think about them, because I thought (perhaps mistakenly) that you were a beginner. Regarding your assertion about none solutions, here my point of view: take the graph of the function $$y = 3\arccos (Bx)-\arccos(Ax)$$. This graphic is always bounded within an interval and if $3\alpha- \beta$, is out of this interval there is no solution. Taking for instance,$(A,B)=(7,4)$, you have $2.636\le y\le 3.648$ therefore if $3\alpha-\beta=4$ you have no solution. I'm right?

Comment: I think not. If you look to the original problem you can always think of it as finding the values of $x$ where the sinusoids $A \cos (x + \alpha)$ and $B \cos (3x + \beta)$ intersect each other. For $A \ne 0$ and $B \ne 0$ they will infinitely many times and sort of periodically, independently of the values of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Maybe my viewpoint is not right. It is your job discern about it if you want. Regards.(Actually I am wrong but it could be interesting analizing where is my mistake)